# How to retrieve the URL of a RequestEntity obtained from RequestEntity.post(String, Object...)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Boot 2.6.1 with Spring Web MVC, and in my controller, I want to get the received `RequestEntity` instead of only the request body, because I have to use information such as the URL.

When I want to test my controller, I build a `RequestEntity` with the following code:

```
RequestEntity<String> r = RequestEntity.post("http://www.example.com/{path}", "myPath").body("");
```

Now, I don't know how to retrieve the URL information from that RequestEntity:

`r.getUrl()` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` because there is no URL in the `RequestEntity`.

When looking at the code in `RequestEntity.body(String)`, I see that the returned object is an `UriTemplateRequestEntity` extending `RequestEntity`, but this object seems to always have an null URL according to its constructor. Only the `uriTemplate`, `uriVarsArray` and `uriVarsMap` attributes are set. But these attributes are not part of `RequestEntity`.

How can I retrieve the URL information from `r`, without casting it to an `UriTemplateRequestEntity`? Is that a bug in `RequestEntity.getUrl()` I should report?

NB: My workaround is the following:

```
RequestEntity<String> r = RequestEntity.post(URI.create(format("http://www.example.com/%s", "myPath"))).body("");
```

or

```
RequestEntity<String> r = RequestEntity.post(URI.create("http://www.example.com/{path}".replaceAll("\\{path\\}", "myPath"))).body("");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HttpServletRequest` in controller parameter like below:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String test(HttpServletRequest httpReq){
    String url=httpReq.getRequestURL().toString();
    // More code
}
```